# How are huge industrial robots powered?

Tags: power, industrial-robot

Take a look at [this monster lifting a car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69RtLBImXiU).

Now I don't think one can get that power by plugging into a wall outlet. So how are these huge robots (their servos) powered? Gasoline? How is power stored, if it needs to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Industrial Robots with having as aim manipulation of large objects are powered electrically in almost all cases (30-40 years ago there have been popular hydraulic variants).

Industrial robots are powered by industrial 400V 3 phase current, so in a sense, they are plugged in a wall outlet, but but a household wall outlet but an industrial one, like [this](http://www.industrialextensionleads.co.uk/ekmps/shops/bazzer1/resources/Design/400-44-4p-plug-dimensions-a.jpg).

[image]

A typical household single-phase outlet in Europe can supply a 16 Ampere current at 230 Volts, that is about 3.68 kVA. As a comparison, high payload Fanuc Robot (similar to the one in the question), the M-900iA, equipped with an R-30iB controller requires an industrial 3 phase outlet which can supply 18kVA. Documentation [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi50dePzs3PAhWLuhQKHcSGBRMQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.setup.com.br%2Fdownload%2Findex.php%3Fpath%3DFanuc%252F%26download%3DR30iB%2520Installation%2520Information%2520.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGamqpjeZZMs0oQ8RXfr34FZIgPvw&sig2=WODru7wBBHcjeyq9JcbVCA). This translates to a current consumption of 25.981 Amperes at 400V supply voltage.

Note1: Most industrial robot have a spring system to easier cope with high payloads by balancing the load of axis 2.

Comment: Could you expand on this Note1? Kinda off-topic but I'm curious of the mechanics for how these spring systems help. Great answer btw will accept! =)

Comment: They are usually hydro/pneu springs, so no mechanics :). The are pre-tensioned, so they always try to pull axis 2 up. This reduces the required torque of the motor in axis two. Here is a patent about it: http://www.google.com/patents/US20110072930

Comment: And that mechanism is present in the video I linked in the question?

Comment: yep. that yellow cylinder behind axis 2 connected with a rotation joint (black  spot) to the linkage. http://www.fanuc.eu/~/media/corporate/products/robots/m2000/m2000-900l/600x400/m-2000ia-900l-handling-tractor-banner.jpg

Comment: It's always best to avoid blanket statements: http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/industrial-robots/geckoinspired-window-washing-robot-is-powered-entirely-by-water *8')

Comment: You are right about blanket statments, I have corrected it. However, question was related to industrial robots, not service robots. Your example is a service robot.